# How can I use bluetooth in google app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to create a button that `onClick`, runs a client-side `script(myFunction();)` to connect to a Bluetooth device through Chrome.

However, it returns the following error:

> SecurityError: requestDevice() called from cross-origin iframe.

The code to request the Bluetooth is as follows:

```
/* jshint esnext:true */
function myFunction() {
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['heart_rate'] }] })
.then(device => { /* ... */ })
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
}
```